# ftp_connect fails for networksolution hosting using PHP

Tags: php, apache, ftp

Why `ftp_connect ()` fails for networksolution hosting using PHP? and produce following error as:

> 500: Internal server error This error is generated when a script
>   running on the server could not be implemented or permissions are
>   incorrectly assigned for files or directories
>
> Troubleshooting suggestions:
>
> Temporarily disable any rewrite rules by renaming your .htaccess file
>   if it exists.
>
> Ensure that any CGI or Perl scripts have at least .755. permissions.
>
> If trying to run PHP and you get this error, you may have an invalid
>   php.ini in your /cgi-bin, or may be missing your php.dat file in this
>   folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error 500 indicates a fatal error in the PHP code.

The only reason I can imagine, why the `ftp_connect` can fail fatally, is that the function actually does not exist. Meaning, your PHP installation was built without an FTP support.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php

*What does `function_exists("ftp_connect")` return?*